# Facebook Canvas unable to get profile picture

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-canvas, facebook-unity-sdk

First time using Facebook Unity SDK, and it was able to download user's profile picture fine in Editor. However when I tried to test it on Facebook Canvas, it wasn't able to download it.

```
You are trying to load data from a www stream which had the following error when downloading.
Failed downloading
https://graph.facebook.com/useridhere/picture?access_token=usertokenhere
```

Why did that happen?

I tried either of both commands:

```
FB.API ("me?fields=picture.type(small)", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, LogCallback);
FB.API ("/me/picture", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, LogCallback);
```

I am using 5.0.4 of the SDK

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug that is being worked on: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/364606280347510/